# Error in pytion subprocess check_output with variable

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, ffprobe

I need the output of my ffprobe command. so I used subprocess module as follow:

```
lengthofvideo = subprocess.check_output('ffprobe', '-i' %inputfile, '-show_entries', 'format=duration', '-v', 'quiet', '-of', 'csv="p=0"')
```

input file variable contains the full bash-like path to video. But my syntax has an error and I got the following error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I do that was to create a command and then pass it to the subprocess:

```
cmd = 'ffprobe -i ' + inputfile + ' -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"'
lengthofvideo = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```